# Adding Transition to background:linear-gradient

Tags: html, css

this is my HTML:

```
<nav role="navigation">
<div align="center">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="games.php">Games</a></li>
<li><a href="trivia.php">Trivia</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
nav {
 background:linear-gradient(#0099cc,#0e2377);
 width: 100%;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 12px 2px #000;
 height: 80px;
}

nav ul {
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

nav li {
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 80px;
 font-size: 28px;
 word-spacing: 12px;
}

nav a {
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 padding-top: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
}

nav li:hover a {
 color: #fff;
}

nav li:hover { 
 background:linear-gradient(#cc0000,#660000);
 height: 80px;
}
```

Here's a JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/z6rae3fL/

How do I add the following CSS when someone hovers over the `<li>`? I understand this is quite tricky because it's a linear-gradient

```
 transition: .4s;
 -moz-transition: .4s;
 -webkit-transition: .4s;
 -ms-transition: .4s;
```

Comment: Linear gradients are images (or almost like images) and so I don't think you would be able to transition from one gradient to a completely different one. Your best bet is probably to look at transitioning the positions.

Comment: You can't animate gradients.   The closest you can get is to have two nodes stacked on top of each other, one with each gradient you want, and transition the opacity of the top one.

Comment: Could you possibly post a code example of that please? @DanielBeck

Comment: posted as answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can get is to have two nodes stacked on top of each other, one with each gradient you want, and transition the opacity of the top one:

```css
#container {
  position:relative; width: 100px;height:100px;
}

#one, #two {
  position:absolute; top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
}

#one {
  background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
}

#two {
  background: linear-gradient(white, black);
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

#two:hover {
  opacity:0
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm having a bit of trouble applying that to my code however, would you be able to help?

Comment: (But note the duplicated link, one in the transitioning absolute-positioned element and one in the static inline element.  That was a cheap hack to get the sizes to match up -- if your `<li>`s had a fixed width you could absolutely-position the links just like the `.hoverGradient` and leave `.hoverGradient` empty.  Leaving the link inline lets it set its own width, which you want, but stacks it underneath the absolutely-positioned gradient, which you don't want.   TBH I don't really recommend you use this technique, it works as a demo but it's all a bit of a hack.